# How to modify inherited class for additional parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, pytorch

I am working on a problem statement related to python classes:

I have two classes:

```
class MCC(object):
    
    def __init__(self, problem_type, batch_size, dataset):
        
        self.problem_type = problem_type
        self.batch_size   = batch_size
        self.dataset      = dataset
        self.cls_weights  = weights_calculation()
        
    
    def weights_calculation(self):
        class_weights        = (1 - (self.dataset['labels'].value_counts().sort_index()/len(self.dataset))).values
        return class_weights
```

second class

```
from transformers import Trainer
class WeightedTrainer(Trainer):

    def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):
        outputs        = model(**inputs)
        logits         = outputs.get('logits')
        labels         = inputs.get('labels')
        loss_func      = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight = self.class_weights)
        loss           = loss_func(logits, labels)
        return (loss, outputs) if return_outputs else loss
```

In the second class, I have to pass `weight` in `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` as in code `loss_func      = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight = self.class_weights)`

I want to modify the inherited `Trainer class` to pass a new parameter `custom_class_weight` in  `MCC` class.

What I have tried:

```
class MCC(object):
    def __init__(self, problem_type, batch_size, dataset, model):
        
        self.problem_type    = problem_type
        self.batch_size      = batch_size
        self.dataset         = dataset
        self.model           = model
        
        self.cls_weights     = weights_calculation()
        self.WeightedTrainer = WeightedTrainer(self.cls_weights)
        self.trainer         = self.WeightedTrainer(self.model)



    def weights_calculation(self):
        class_weights        = (1 - (self.dataset['labels'].value_counts().sort_index()/len(self.dataset))).values
        return class_weights



class WeightedTrainer(Trainer):

    def __init__(self, custom_class_weight):
        self.custom_class_weight = custom_class_weight

    def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):
        outputs        = model(**inputs)
        logits         = outputs.get('logits')
        labels         = inputs.get('labels')
        loss_func      = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight = self.custom_class_weight)
        loss           = loss_func(logits, labels)
        return (loss, outputs) if return_outputs else loss
```

Which is disturbing the inherited's Trainer class properties and thus giving me an error:

```
TypeError: 'WeightedTrainer' object is not callable
```

I also tried:

```
class WeightedTrainer(Trainer):

    def __init__(self, custom_class_weight, **kwargs,):
        self.custom_class_weight = custom_class_weight
        super(WeightedTrainer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):
        outputs        = model(**inputs)
        logits         = outputs.get('logits')
        labels         = inputs.get('labels')
        loss_func      = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight = self.custom_class_weight)
        loss           = loss_func(logits, labels)
        return (loss, outputs) if return_outputs else loss
```

How to create a child class, using the Trainer class as a parent class and modify an inherited class while keeping all default properties of super class?

Comment: `__init__` is not special with inheritance. If you want to run the parent's `__init__`, you need to do `super().__init__(...)`. And if you want the `__init__` to also accept the same arguments as the paren't s `__init__`, the child's `__init__` should accept them as well and pass them to `super().__init__`

Comment: When are you getting the error you mentioned? What is `Trainer`? Does the `Trainer` class have those three attribute assignments at the bottom of its `__init__`?

Comment: @decorator-factory while calling WeightedTrainer in another class.

Comment: It's not very clear to me how the two classes you show interact with each other. Nothing in `WeightedTrainer` appears to be using `MCC`, nor vice versa. If there's a relationship between the classes, it's not obvious from the code you've shown, so you really need to explain it to us.

Comment: @Blckknght Please check in MCC class it's ```self.WeightedTrainer = WeightedTrainer(self.cls_weights)```

Comment: Can you show the code that causes the error and the traceback of the error?

Comment: `self.WeightedTrainer` is an instante of the `WeightedTrainer` class, it is not a callable object, so the line `self.trainer = self.WeightedTrainer(self.model)` is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for @JMA valuable comment, Here is the fix.

I was calling `self.WeightedTrainer` which is not a callable object. Full working code:

```
class MCC(object):
    def __init__(self, problem_type, batch_size, dataset, model):
        
        self.problem_type    = problem_type
        self.batch_size      = batch_size
        self.dataset         = dataset
        self.model           = model
        
        self.cls_weights     = weights_calculation()
        self.custom_trainer  = WeightedTrainer
        self.trainer         = self.WeightedTrainer(self.model, custom_class_weight = self.cls_weights)


    def weights_calculation(self):
        class_weights        = (1 - (self.dataset['labels'].value_counts().sort_index()/len(self.dataset))).values
        return class_weights



class WeightedTrainer(Trainer):

    def __init__(self, custom_class_weight, **kwargs,):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.custom_class_weight = custom_class_weight

    def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):
        outputs        = model(**inputs)
        logits         = outputs.get('logits')
        labels         = inputs.get('labels')
        loss_func      = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight = self.custom_class_weight)
        loss           = loss_func(logits, labels)
        return (loss, outputs) if return_outputs else loss
```

Comment: Is this code working? I expect it to result in a `SyntaxError` as you are passing the positional arguments before the keyword arguments, which afaik is not allowed in Python.

Comment: @JMA corrected. This is just a demo code, not an actual code.